# PHP models : one or more setters by database action?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model, naming

I'm using the MVC pattern in a CodeIgniter PHP project and I'm wondering what's the best way to build methods of the models in order to ensure readability of the code and scalability.

In short, is this better to do this ? :

```
public function set_account_state($new_state) {
    // UPDATE a database record state to $new_state [0, 1 or 2]
}
```

Or this ? :

```
public function reject_account() {
    // UPDATE a database record state to 0  
}

public function accept_account() {
    // UPDATE a database record state to 1
}

public function pending_account() {
    // UPDATE a database record state to 2
}
```

Or maybe another way ?
Also, is there a good practice for function naming in such cases ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function set_account_state($state)
```

This is better when you have only one task and that is to change the state.
But if in future you might have to do different tasks before you change the account state then you need three different methods. 
You can still have that original method to change the state of the account and call it from your three methods.

Function naming should include a verb with nouns to make it clearer. 
function pending_account() is not that clear, function keep_account_pending() is I feel a better way to name it.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Account state management is in one place as it should be. Valid values for `$state` can be serviced by constants thereby improving readability and understanding of what the argument values should/could be. That doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't create private or protected "helper" functions in the class to handle each particular state. But the public interface should be a single function.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the second way is the better way.

Using names that indicate what will the method do can improve the readability of the code.

As your code grows bigger, it's easy to forget what number represents what state. That does not happen with names because a method called `reject_account()` will indicate that account will be rejected better then a number passed as argument to a function.

Also when other people work on your code, it will be easier for them to understand what is going on when a method is called. Having said that, it's better for one understand that the client account is accepted when one sees a method called `accept_account()` then when one sees `set_account_state(1)`.